Effect of any one dysfunctional diode in a bridge rectifier

In these bridge rectifiers what if a diode becomes like fully dysfunctional, and stops conducting totally in a direction. I was wondering if the output voltage will be like a half wave pulsating DC? Will the wave even start from time t=0 because that may depend upon which diode is damaged right? I am confused a lot...

It seems from your message that you use the right kind of logic to analyze what happens. So what exactly is still confusing you?

I am confused : "Will the wave even start from time t=0 because that may depend upon which diode is damaged right?" I mean, does the pulsating half wave DC start from time t=0 or after a half cycle?. Doesn't that depend on which diode is dysfunctional? Can you explain that to me please?

In my view, yiur question "Doesn't that depend on which diode is dysfunctional?" is a self-answering question. There is hardly anything left to explain to you! (Or perhaps an approach to see it in full detail might be to draw the voltages on the different points of the circuit as a function of time, and do that for cases where dysfunctional diodes are simply treated as absent. That may illustrate very explicitly what happens. And also of course that for shorted dysfunctional diodes something else will happen!)

For shorted one, that would behaving as a closed circuit right?... throughout the cycle..
